# agregar evento con addevenlistener

Tags: javascript, events

quiero agregar unos eventos  a unos input['text'], me gustaria hacerlo limpio y añadirlos desde javascript .
Pero no consigo que funcionen, como deberia hacerlo?
Asi es como intenté hacerlo funcionar

````
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}
var prueba = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')[4];
prueba.addEventListener('keypress', soloNumeros(e));
```
````

Comment: Este cógido que noes expones, ¿qué fallo da?

Comment: pues que no agrega el evento, puedo utilizar letras y números igualmente

Comment: Agregar un listener no te da esa funcionalidad

Comment: Es decir ¿quieres que a varios `inputs` se les aplique el mismo método que impide que escribas cualquier otro valor menos números no?

Comment: no entiendo muy bien que quieres decir

Comment: exacto,  eso quiero

Comment: Ahí estas solo retornando teclas, eso no quiere decir que las demas no se ejecuten, solo estas obteniendo el valor de las teclas, tecnicamente tu listener si funciona.

Comment: en el html5, puse return a la funcion, y  ahi me va. Pero no sé cómo hacerlo en javascript aqui tengo el ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/xhj6fucr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres cancelar el comportamiento predeterminado de una tecla basta con asignar en el evento un rango en donde no es pulsable:

```
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;

    if(!(key >= 48 && key <= 57)){
        e.preventDefault();
    }    

    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}
```

Comment: Por cierto si esto lo requires para el input donde esta el campo celular o telefono o algo así, te recomiendo que uses mas bien esto: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_tel.asp en vez de cambiar el comportamiento por defecto de cualquier tecla que no sea un numero.

Comment: muchas gracias , perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puedes proceder de este modo:

- Obtienes todos los elementos con `querySelectorAll()` por medio de la clase asignada
- Recorres la variable que contiene a los elementos previamente recuperados
- De cada elemento obtenido en las iteraciones le asignas el evento de `keyup`
- Puedes validar por medio de una regex donde indiques que solo sean números así `[0-9]`
- Considerando que la regex validará y devolverá `true` o `false` según sea el caso validas con un `if else`

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Solo números</h1>
    <input type="text" class="soloElementos">
    <input type="text" class="soloElementos">
    <input type="text" class="soloElementos">
    <input type="text" class="soloElementos">
    <script>
        let soloNumeros = document.querySelectorAll(".soloElementos")
        
        soloNumeros.forEach((elemento) => {
          elemento.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
            let testeo = /[0-9]/.test(elemento.value)
            if (testeo) {
              console.log("Bien todo es número")
            } else {
              console.log("Hiciste algo mal")
            }
          })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: gracias por la explicacion (Y)